# Recyclerview shows each item at full screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a requirement to use ConstraintLayouts for all layout files. I have created a layout file as follows:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contactThumbImage"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/someimage"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/someimage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtContactName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contactThumbImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtContactEmail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contactThumbImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtContactName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My adapter is as follows:

```
class ContactsAdapter(var contacts: List<ContactEntry>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return contacts.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val contact = contacts[position]
        holder.mName.text = "${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}"
        holder.mAddress.text = contact.email
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var contactImage: ImageView
        var mName: TextView
        var mAddress: TextView

        init{
            contactImage = view.findViewById(R.id.contactThumbImage)
            mName = view.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName)
            mAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.txtContactEmail)
        }
    }
}
```

And in my activity's onCreate method:

```
    emailContactsRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    ContactsManager.getContactsWithEmailAddresses(this).let { contacts ->
        if (contacts.size < 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Currently you have no email contacts to list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            emailContactsRecycler.adapter = ContactsAdapter(contacts)
        }
    }
```

I have four contacts on the test device and have verified that the `ContactsAdapter` is being instantiated with the correct data.

When I run the app, each item of the recycler take up the full screen giving the impression that only one item has been returned.

**NOTE**: when using any height attribute like wrap_content on my ConstraintLayout, the app becomes unresponsive and shows only a black screen. The only setting that does not crash the app is match_parent

I've tried different layout types without any success. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: You've set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on the  `<ConstraintLayout>`. Change it to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Change Height of Constraint Layout to wrap content.

Comment: Well, I don't use `ConstraintLayout`, so I'm not sure how it behaves with `wrap_content`, but I wouldn't think that should freeze the app. Are you sure they aren't just shrinking to zero height, and your app only seems non-responsive 'cause there's nothing on-screen? Also, it seems rather odd to have to use `ConstraintLayout`, especially for `RecyclerView` items. It's about the slowest `ViewGroup` overall, considering everything it does. Are you sure you can't use something else, if just for those items?

Answer (score 4):

You have defined `match_parent` for `width` and `height` attributes for your top parent layout (`ConstraintLayout`). Match parent value will take whole space of the parent, so it works as expected. You can try to use `wrap_content` for the `height` attribute.

You should also add minimum one constraint to the bottom of the parent (e.g. for `ImageView` layout).

Comment: It's very strange that setting any height attribute on the ConstraintLayout other than match_parent causes the app to become unresponsive. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Could you post your updated xml? With the wrap_content and constraint from inside view which will be set to parent bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Define the `height` attribute of item as `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

As `android:layout_height="match_parent"` contains the height according to parent's height and  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` contains the height according to content of view.

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace layout xml with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contactThumbImage"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtContactName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contactThumbImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtContactEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contactThumbImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtContactName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp">
```